# I have writing more than 300 rating and review so here display all review but i want to display as pagination?

Tags: magento-1.9, review, pagination, ratings

I have writing  more than 300 rating and review so here display all review but i want to display as pagination if any better solution please suggest me.

[image]

because when product view more than 1500 goes its not good appear for customer as well as site.

Comment: Try this 


in your collection use this

     $collection = Mage::getModel('...')
                ->getCollection()
                ->setPageSize(20)
                ->setCurPage(1);

Comment: yes its working to set the limit for review, but how can i set pagination? @Kothari

Comment: try this http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/18/magento-collection-paging/